# Problem with multiple Audio Clips in Instagram

Tags: spark-ar-studio

So I got a conditional statement to switch between two audio clips (.m4a, mono, 44.1kHz, acc) as inputs for the audio player.

In SparkAR everything works as intended, but in Instagram I can only hear the song which should be played when the condition is false. Like the "default".

Here is my setup:

[image: Setup]

Unfortunately I can't send you the project or a preview of the filter as it's confidential work for an upcoming release of a musician.

I also tried using two speakers and changing their volume according to the conditional statement. But that doesn't work either.

I'm guessing it has something to do with using the wrong type for output in the condition? But there is no audioclip type and it works for one song, so I'm not sure.

Has anybody ever had a similiar problem and knows how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this somehow?

Comment: @rdshck nope, unfortunately not. seems to be some build-in restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved a similar problem utilizing multiple speakers, one for each audio clip:

[image]

Comment: different speakers! that's smart, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. On Instagram, check whether the condition passed to IF patch changes to TRUE or not.
2. I hope you have set the Patch Type of IF patch to "Text".